# Google cloud: How to list all service-accounts from all Projects in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, service-accounts, google-iam

I have requirement to get all the properties of a service account in google cloud. is it possible to list all the properties something like Select *.

otherwise i need the following information:

- SA account name
- Email address
- Iam Role assigned
- User managed Keys (if any)
- account creation date
- last used /authentication time.
- Project name
- account status (enable / disable)

I can get all the projects then all the service accounts in it but i dont know how to get all other values.

```
foreach ($project in gcloud projects list --format="value(projectId)")
{
  Write-Host "ProjectId: $project"
  foreach ($robot in  gcloud iam service-accounts list --project $project --format="value(email)")
  {
     Write-Host "    -> Robot $robot"
   
  }
}
```

Comment: `gcloud iam service-accounts describe` and `gcloud iam service-accounts keys list` will give you some of the details. Information like **last used** will require parsing Cloud Logging. Log retention defaults to 30 days, so you will want to extend retention time so that you can scan logs beyond that past 30 days.

Comment: that command only give 7 properties, i noticed if i ran another one gcloud iam service-accounts get-iam-policy , it give members and role...is their any scripts available which will list all the properties a service account.

Comment: Did you find all your required information by API call? Some seems impossible to get (last used??) You will have to perform several requests to get every single information

Comment: I dont have experience with API calls so No. Looks like i have to run all available gcloud command for service-accounts to get maximum information. you are correct, last used near to impossible to get.

Comment: You can use the [`list` method](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/list) to get information about service accounts of each project individually. The [response](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts#ServiceAccount) doesn't include some of the fields you are looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the commenters have pointed out, this isn't trivial.

But, I'm always up for some `gcloud`-bashing ;-)

Your code sample suggests you want the answer in PowerShell which I don't have  and hope you don't mind **pointers** (what follows is incomplete) in bash:

Does:

- Project ID
- Account name
- Enabled|Disabled
- Email
- Keys
- Creation (timestamp)

Doesn't:

- Role assignments
- Last used (audit logs?)

```sh
PROJECTS=$(gcloud projects list --format="value(projectId)")

for PROJECT in ${PROJECTS}
do
  echo "Project: ${PROJECT}"
  # Extracts ACCOUNT_ID, EMAIL (==ACCOUNT_ID@...), DISABLED
  ROBOTS=$(\
    gcloud iam service-accounts list \
    --project=${PROJECT} \
    --format="csv[no-heading](displayName.encode(\"base64\"),email,email.split(\"@\").slice(0),disabled)")
  for ROBOT in ${ROBOTS}
  do
    # Parse results
    IFS=, read ENCODED_NAME EMAIL ACCOUNT_ID DISABLED <<< ${ROBOT}
    NAME=$(echo -e ${ENCODED_NAME} | base64 --decode)
    echo "  Service Account: ${NAME}"
    echo "    Disabled: ${DISABLED}"
    echo "    Email: ${EMAIL}"
    # Keys
    KEYS=$(\
        gcloud iam service-accounts keys list \
        --iam-account=${EMAIL} \
        --project=${PROJECT} \
        --format="value(name.scope(keys))")
    for KEY in ${KEYS}
    do
      echo "    Key: ${KEY}"
    done
    # Creation (Only searches back 30-days!)
    FILTER=""\
"logName=\"projects/${PROJECT}/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity\" "\
"resource.type=\"service_account\" "\
"protoPayload.methodName=\"google.iam.admin.v1.CreateServiceAccount\" "\
"protoPayload.request.account_id=\"${ACCOUNT_ID}\" "

    LOG=$(\
        gcloud logging read "${FILTER}" \
        --project=${PROJECT} \
        --format=json \
        --freshness=30d \
        --format="value(timestamp)")
    echo "    Created: ${LOG}"
  done
done
```

**Notes**

- Service Account creation times -- IIUC -- can only be obtained through audit logs (`CreateServiceAccount[Key]`). One challenge with this is having to search back through the project's (entire) history to find these.
- Only user-created Service Accounts are created (during the project's lifetime). Google-maintained account e.g. App Engine will not be found.
- The script searches the logs for **each** account. This is inefficient and it would be better to search the logs once for all accounts and then merge the results.
- Role assignments is difficult because of inheritance. A naive solution would get the IAM policy for each Project but this is insufficient as it doesn't cover Organizational|Folder permissions nor does it include resource-specific bindings.
- I actually don't know how to grep the logs for last auth times and assume this is available through audit logs
- Apologies for the gnarly `base64` encoding of the account's `displayName`. This is to avoid over-eager parsing of (the majority of) names that include spaces. There's likely a better approach.

Comment: You are now the **cloud script master**

Comment: thank you @DazWilkin, i will try and update here...Once again thank you for your efforts.

Comment: Nice! Creation and expiry time can be extracted with --format="csv[no-heading](name.scope(keys),validAfterTime,validBeforeTime)"  assuming they're the same thing. It does break the formatting of $KEYS though.

Answer (score 0):

Taking @DazWilin's excellent script, with a few mods it generates a Service Account Register or CSV file of all the service accounts, including their descriptions and keys. Removing the log scrape speeds it up.

```bash
#! /bin/bash
# Requires permission to list projects, list service accounts, view keys
if [ $# -lt 1 ]
then
  echo "usage:  $0 csv_output_file"
  exit
fi

gcloud projects list --format="value(projectId)" --sort-by=projectId
OUTFILE=$1
FILTER='prefix'
PROJECTS=$(gcloud projects list --format="value(projectId)" --filter="${FILTER}")

echo "Project,ServiceAccountName,Account Name,Email,Description,key_id,key_created_at,key_expires_at" > $OUTFILE

for PROJECT in ${PROJECTS}
do
  echo "Project: ${PROJECT}"
  # Extracts ACCOUNT_ID, EMAIL (==ACCOUNT_ID@...), DISABLED, DESCRIPTION
  ROBOTS=$(\
    gcloud iam service-accounts list \
    --project=${PROJECT} \
     --format="csv[no-heading](displayName.encode(\"base64\"),email,email.split(\"@\").slice(0),disabled,description.encode(\"base64\"))")

  #echo $ROBOTS
  for ROBOT in ${ROBOTS}
  do
    # Parse results
    IFS=, read ENCODED_NAME EMAIL ACCOUNT_ID DISABLED ENCODED_DESCR<<< ${ROBOT}
    NAME=$(echo -e ${ENCODED_NAME} | base64 --decode)
    DESCR=$(echo -e ${ENCODED_DESCR} | base64 --decode)
    echo "  Service Account: ${NAME}"
    echo "    Disabled: ${DISABLED}"
    echo "    Email: ${EMAIL}"
    echo "    Descr: ${DESCR}"
    RESPONSE=$(\
        gcloud iam service-accounts keys list \
        --iam-account=${EMAIL} \
        --project=${PROJECT} \
        --format="csv[no-heading](name.scope(keys),validAfterTime,validBeforeTime)" \
        )
    IFS=$'\n' rows=($RESPONSE)
    for row in "${rows[@]}"
    do
        echo "$PROJECT,$NAME, $ACCOUNT_ID,$EMAIL,$DESCR,$row" >> $OUTFILE
        # IFS=$',' args=($row)
        # keyname=args[0]
        # created=args[1]
        # expires=args[2]
    done
  done
done
```