# I need to list Service Accounts with name, role and password for projects in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

I need to list service accounts with their name, role and service account key on Google Cloud Platform. I need a script or cmd that I can use whenever I want to automatically fetch all the services accounts, doing it manually wouldn't help me.

I already checked GCloud CLI and tried the cmd `gcloud iam service-accounts list` with a lot of filters, but I can't get the information that I want.

I tried to use Asset Inventory with the `Principal types : serviceaccount` filter on all projects but I get a lot of repeated service accounts. The final number doesn't match.

Does anyone know how to do it? I've already checked a lot of documentation and I can't get it.

Comment: did you try `gcloud iam service-accounts describe XXXX`? Ok, you have to iterate over all the service accounts but you should have what you need. Just a note, you will just have the key ID not the whole service account key file.

Comment: After a check, you also need to loop over the command ` gcloud beta iam service-accounts keys list --iam-account=XXXX` to get the keyID

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere thanks for your answer. My idea is to execute a command/script and receive all the information, If I run DESCRIBE, I don't get roles and keys.

Comment: can you check this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68324675/google-cloud-how-to-list-all-service-accounts-from-all-projects-in-gcp) which can help you to reslove your issue.

Comment: You have to compose many command to have your result. A script is the right thing to do.